# Why is self.skipWaiting() and self.clients.claim() not default behaviour for service workers

Tags: service-worker, service-worker-events

I'm researching service workers for my thesis. I understand how the lifecycle works, but I'm having trouble understanding the default update behaviour of service workers.

When installing a new service worker, while an old one is installed, the service worker will have to wait to activate. With self.skipWaiting() and self.clients.claim() it is possible to fully activate the service worker and control the pages. I don't get why this is not default behaviour. The main reason I can find is to preserve code and data consistency (https://redfin.engineering/service-workers-break-the-browsers-refresh-button-by-default-here-s-why-56f9417694). With some basic understanding of the lifecycle, shouldn't it be possible to preserve both code and data consistency when a service worker updates or am I missing something? Are there any additional reasons?

Also has this behaviour been different in the past? Have skipWaiting() and clients.claim() been added afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

The default - as it is now - is safer in general and doesn't force everyone to come up with all sorts of solutions.

1. User loads page with main1.js, SWv1 registers 1 second later, site now fully cached
2. User loads the page again - this time from cache by SWv1, super fast. New SWv2 registers 1 second later, caches new assets (main1.js is now main2.js), takes control via skipWaiting and clientsClaim

Two things can happen now:

Page has loaded with main1.js and the browser has executed whatever that script said. User has interacted with the page etc. Page is running main1.js which expects to be talking to SWv1 but actually the SW in control is SWv2. The script, main1.js, could be sending messages and trying to interact with the SW in a way that only SWv1 understood but v2 doesn't have any idea about. Now the page breaks because of the mismatch.

SWv1 cached all assets that site v1 needed. Thus if main1.js was to lazyload something etc. when user interacted with the page, browser would get that from the cache. As SWv2 has taken control and cached its idea of the assets (these are now newer assets), when main1.js tries to lazyload something originally cached by SWv1 it's not found. Also, because this is now a new deployment, the asset is not on the HTTP server anymore. It would have been in caches handled by SWv1 but SWv2 doesn't know about it. SWv2 knows about a newer version of that file. Page breaks.

It is important to understand that this might not be the case for every site/SW combination. If you have very little logic in the SW script and the main.js doesn't communite with sw.js too much it is possible to build a combination where skipWaiting and clientsClaim don't cause any problems. You can also code in such a way that if an error happens, you'll show the user a notification to refresh.